# Integrating dynamic c lib.so to python

Tags: python, image, numpy

I was trying to Integrate shared library written in c to already running python application. for that i have created a simple .so file and trying to access the function written in shared lib.

```
from ctypes import *
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
print cv.__version__

so= 'ContrastEnhancement.so'
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(so)

image = cv.imread('python1.jpg')
image_data = np.array(image)

#calling shared lib function here
lib.ContrastStretch(image_data, width ,height, 5,10)
cv.imwrite("python_result.jpg", )
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test1.py", line 21, in <module>
  lib.ContrastStretch(image_data, width ,height, 5,10)



ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

if i have tried this like

```
 lib.ContrastStretch(c_uint8(image_data), width ,height, 5,10)
 TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Now it seems like it is nothing to do with shared lib but 'how to use image data   (arrays) in python'

thanks 
   javed

Comment: What kind of data does your `ContrastStretch` function take?

Comment: ``ctype`` works well if you want to integrate simple C code into Python. By simple I mean that only simple type are exchanged. I would suggest to use a more advanced Python/C wrapper than c-type. ``Cython`` (cython.org) is a good one. Moreover, it works well with numpy.

Comment: prototypes for ContrastStretch is:    int eiContrastStretch( unsigned char *pImgData, int width, int height, int low, int high)

Comment: Irrelevant to answer .. @hivert is right , ctype works well but you will face major difficulties using it , so use cython instead .. it converts your `x.py` file to `x.so` which can be directly used as module import in python ex: `import x` ..

Comment: Thanks hivert, i will try it with cython also. I am not exact getting what kind of problem with code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ctypes doesn't know the signature of the function in the shared library. Before calling the function, you have to let ctypes know its signature. This is a little bit of a pain with ctypes, because it has its own little mini language for doing this.

I would recommend using cffi. Cython is an option too, but if you're just using cython to wrap  c libraries, there's often a lot of annoying overhead, and you have to basically learn a whole new language (cython). Yeah, it's similar to python in syntax, but understanding and optimizing cython performance requires actually reading the generated C in my experience.

With cffi (docs: http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.7/), your code would be something like this:

```
import cffi
ffi = cffi.FFI()

# paste the function signature from the library header file
ffi.cdef('int ContrastStretch(double* data, int w0 ,int h0, int wf, int hf)

# open the shared library
C = ffi.dlopen('ContrastEnhancement.so')

img = np.random.randn(10,10)

# get a pointer to the start of the image
img_pointer = ffi.cast('double*', img.ctypes.data)
# call a function defined in the library and declared here with a ffi.cdef call
C.ContrastStretch(img_pointer, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 5, 10)
```